# unknown error swagger 2.0 path ref issue

Tags: path, yaml, swagger

I'm trying to run the following code:

```
/v1/test/{id}:
    x-swagger-router-controller: Security
    get:
      operationId: test      
      description: "Test jwt middleware and multiple paths"      
      security:
        - JWT: []
      parameters:
      - name: "id"
        in: "path"
        description: "ID of user"
        required: true
        type: "integer"      
      responses:
        "200":
          description: "Success"
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/LoginSuccess"
        "403":
          description: "Access Denied"
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/Error"  
/v2/test/{id}:            
      $ref: "#/paths/~1v1~1test~1{id}"
```

But i'm receiving the following error:

> API Errors:
>
> #/paths/~1v2~1test~1{id}/$ref: Path could not be resolved:
>
> ## /paths/~1v1~1test~1{id}

How can i fix this?

Comment: The path `$ref`erence looks valid. Which tool produces this error?

Comment: On an unrelated note, you need to remove the `operationId`. Otherwise after the path `$ref` is resolved, both operations end up with the same `operationId`, which is not valid.

Comment: This is what I get when I start it up: Its in expressjs. The OperationId is tying it to the method to run. If I remove how can it execute the function?

Comment: Re `operationId`: No idea, just pointing out the spec errors. It looks like the tool you are using does not support `$ref` under path items. If you are using https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-node, open an issue on GitHub. Meanwhile you'll probably need to replace the path `$ref` with the inline path definition.

Comment: In the end I approached in a different way and just added a path template {apiversion} into the path and achieved the same thing which was to allow api/v1 api/v2 etc to the same function when there was no new v2 method. Thanks

Comment: Great. Consider posting your solution as an answer to this Q.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case what I really needed to achieve was to be able to version my API especially where not all methods had a newer version yet ie where for example /api/v1/method and /api/v2/method were still destined for the same function.

I thus solved it as follows

```
parameters:
       - name: version
         in: path
         description: Version number of API
         required: true
         type: string
         enum: &APIVERSION
           - v1
           - v2
```

In this way both v1 and v2 went to the same place. I can also add v3 etc to the enum which is reusable by different paths as enum: *APIVERSION